# Define mandatory object keys in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My question is it possible could i define mandatory object keys in my javascript function?

Mandatory field-> phone,email,city,country

If mandatory object key never define during input, function able to handle missing object key with empty value to proceed to insert.

Anyone could help on this ?

Input

```
{
    "data": [{
        "name": "John",
        "contact": {
            "phone": "987-654-3210",
             "email": "john123@xyz.com",
             "city": "Berlin",
             "country": "Germany"
        }
    }]
}
```

This is my code

```
  function insertData(inputData) {
    var data = inputData.data;
    var query = "";

    data.forEach(function (item) {
        var name = item.name;

        Object.keys(item).forEach(function (detail) {
            if (detail !== "name") {
                var detailData = item[detail];

                Object.keys(detailData).forEach(function (type) {
                    var value = detailData[type];

                    query += `begin
                                insert into [dbname].[dbo].[table] (name, detail, type, value)
                                values('` + name + `', '` + detail + `', '` + type + `', '` + value + `')
                              end; `;
                });
            }
        });
    });

    return query;
}
```

SQL table Output

| name | detail | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | contact | phone | 987-654-3210 |
| John | contact | email | john123@xyz.com |
| John | contact | city | Berlin |
| John | contact | country | Germany |

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to substitute variables into SQL. Use a prepared statement with parameters.